# Ramme does not open

Tags: 20.04

I've recently installed "Ramme" Instagram client on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop and it's not starting. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I can't open it by clicking. Nothing happens. I read about ramme [here](https://www.fossmint.com/best-ubuntu-apps/) and downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/terkelg/ramme/releases).

Comment: Does anyone know an answer?

Comment: Nobody knows what "Ramme" is.

Comment: What do you mean? @Pilot6

Comment: I mean that I've never heard of this software. Can you extend your question and explain where you got it and how did you install it? Then there is a chance to get some answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 Wait a sec while I boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 I got it from here. https://github.com/terkelg/ramme/releases Read about it  here https://www.fossmint.com/best-ubuntu-apps/

Comment: So [edit] your question and explain all that. But it's better to ask authors of this program for support.

Comment: @Pilot6 New question. Please try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramme is not supported anymore.